# A room full of buttons and numbers

Tags: lateral-thinking

You see a room with two buttons, two numbers and some text. As you enter it, the room expands, and two more buttons, two more numbers and some more text show up. Later someone else enters it, the rooms expands again and two more buttons, two more numbers and some more text show up. Every two buttons come in pairs. There are no text on the buttons. There are shapes on the buttons. You push one button, it lights up and a number increases by one, and a second number increases by five. You then push another button, it lights up a number decreases by one and another number decreases by two. You push a third button, it lights up, but this time two numbers decrease by one and a third number decreases by two. You find the buttons and numbers familiar.

Can you give a clearer explanation of what this mysterious room and everything inside is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the mysterious room is

> A Stack Exchange question page, such as this one,

the buttons are

> The vote buttons,

and the persons entering the room are

> New answers, each with their own set of two vote buttons, an initial score of 0, and with the answerer's rep showing.

Particularly, the first two buttons are

> 1. Upvoting a question: adds one point to the question, and 5 to OP's rep
>  2. Downvoting a question: removes one point from the question and two from OP's rep.

The final button is

> The downvote button on an answer, which removes one point from the answer, two rep from the answerer, and one rep from the downvoter.

Comment: why are you so damn clever and intelligent?

Comment: @iBug Well, he has more than 22K rep so it's not a surprise that he can do this :D

Comment: I’ve just pushed a button to increase a number by 10.

Comment: Can you push the first button? :)